# How to load huge Data with JDBC into a file without running out of memory?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

My problem is that I have a database with huge records(Doublearrays) of GBs. So one single record is up to 3GB. Is there a way to load it in "pieces" and write them into a file?

Im using Java, the JDBC driver and postgresql.

Comment: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that does not address the problem of size of a single row

Comment: Your data model might need a refactor if a single row is multiple GB's

Comment: Select it column by column, instead of select *

Comment: Have you tried anything? I've never used arrays, but the JDBC Array api doc says: "an Array object contains a logical pointer to the data in the SQL ARRAY value rather than containing the ARRAY value's data. The Array interface provides methods for bringing an SQL ARRAY value's data to the client as either an array or a ResultSet object". So it should be possible to iterate through the array elements without loading everything in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using copy to load large amounts of data. This will require some work on your side but likely well worth the effort.

Comment: do you mean grabbing the data with may "hands" from the server?

Answer (score 0):

> So one single record is up to 3GB. Is there a way to load it in "pieces" and write them into a file?

The only "streaming" datatype in current (42.2.3 pgjdbc) is `lob` (`blob`, `clob`).

In case you have 3GB worth of `double[]`, then you have the following options:

1. Allocate more memory (e.g. `-Xmx16G`) and just process it row by row
2. Fetch array contents via multiple SQL executions (e.g. first 100 indices, then next 100, and so on)
3. Create a [pull request](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/pulls) for pgjdbc to support streaming API for `copy` data (currently it provides just `byte[] readFromCopy()`, however streaming can be added there)

Answer (score 0):

try set `FetchSize`. meanwhile connection attribute `AutoCommit` must be false. and `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` is necessary